Overlay points on violin plot using Seaborn
I wish to compare two datasets. To this end, I want to represent the first as a violin and the second as points.
Unfortunately, there is a discrepancy between the two plots, as can be seen in the figure attached to the message.
I am unable to overlay the two plots.
Here is the part of the script that I use.
figure, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10,10))

ax = sns.violinplot(data=df2.rolling(window=3).mean(),   split=False, color="pink")

sns.stripplot(data=df.rolling(window=3).mean(), dodge=True,  linewidth=1, jitter=False, ax=ax)

Here output of df.describe() and df2,describe()
df2.describe()
     Bafoussam

count  1395.000000
mean      7.030180
std      10.730945
min       0.000000
25%       0.000000
50%       2.900000
75%       9.800000
max     102.300003
df.describe()
   Bafoussam    Dschang

count  31.000000  31.000000
mean   16.980645  26.138710
std    25.344683  31.060786
min     0.000000   0.000000
25%     0.000000   0.000000
50%     8.200000   8.100000
75%    24.500000  48.800000
max    96.200000  90.600000


Finally, I reproduced what I wanted by applying this
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,14))
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 2)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1])



sns.violinplot(data=df2["Station1"],   split=False, color="pink", inner=None, ax=ax1)
sns.stripplot(data=df["Statation1"], dodge=True,  linewidth=1, jitter=False, ax=ax1, color="red", size=16)


sns.violinplot(data=df2["Station2"].rolling(window=rday).mean(), inner=None, split=False, color="pink", ax=ax2)
sns.stripplot(data=df["Station2"].rolling(window=rday).mean(), dodge=True,  linewidth=1, jitter=False, ax=ax2, color="red", size=16)



I am using a daily rainfall dataset for a long period (for violin) and a specific year (for stripplot). I want to show the extremeness of this particular year.
Thanks

I added the result of df.describe()

Please add more information, please never add text as image, always as text. Please explain how you expect the plot to look like when df2 has only one column ("0"), and df has two columns.  Please provide some reproducible test data.

These are the asked outputs. I am selecting one column from df
df2.describe()
Out[865]:
Bafoussam
count  1395.000000
mean      7.030180
std      10.730945
min       0.000000
25%       0.000000
50%       2.900000
75%       9.800000
max     102.300003
df.describe()
Out[866]:
Bafoussam    Dschang
count  31.000000  31.000000
mean   16.980645  26.138710
std    25.344683  31.060786
min     0.000000   0.000000
25%     0.000000   0.000000
50%     8.200000   8.100000
75%    24.500000  48.800000
max    96.200000  90.600000

Please add this to the post, not the comments.

I would recommend that you read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?
